# React set parent state from {children}

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello i'm trying to build a loading container component

```
   export const LoadingContainer = () =>{
   const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    return(<div className="loading-container">
      {children}
      {isLoading ? <LoadingSVG>  : ""}
    </div>)
    }
```

But i wonder if there is a way to call setIsloading from the {children} something like this

```
<LoadingContainer>
  <div className="tes">
    <button onClick={setIsLoading(true)}>Start Loading</button> 
 </div>
</LoadingContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Function as a Child

One of the many ways to address this is by using the [function as a child](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render) pattern which is used by [Context.Consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer).

Right now your are passing the child as plain JSX element, like:

```
<LoadingContainer>
   <SomeChild/>
</LoadingContainer>
```

We can instead make the child be a function which receives `setIsLoading` as its argument.  This allows you to write something like this:

```
<LoadingContainer>
  {(setIsLoading) => (
     <div className="tes">
       <button onClick={() => setIsLoading(true)}>Start Loading</button> 
     </div>
  )}
</LoadingContainer>
```

Since `children` is now a function instead of an element, you now call it in your `LoadingContainer` and provide the `setIsLoading` argument.

```
export const LoadingContainer = () => {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

   return(
     <div className="loading-container">
      {isLoading ? <LoadingSVG/> : children(setIsLoading)}
    </div>
   )
}
```

---

If you want to show the `children` all the time, not just when `isLoading` is `false` then you probably want to pass both `isLoading` and `setIsLoading`.  So we can pass them as two properties on an object.

```
<LoadingContainer>
  {({isLoading, setIsLoading}) => (
     <div className="tes">
       <button onClick={() => setIsLoading(!isLoading)}>
         {isLoading ? "Stop Loading" : "Start Loading"}
       </button> 
     </div>
  )}
</LoadingContainer>
```

```
export const LoadingContainer = () => {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

   return(
     <div className="loading-container">
      {isLoading && <LoadingSVG/>}
      {children({isLoading, setIsLoading})}
    </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what i needed, thank you!I never considered this approach (i still have much to learn)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Context API: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

It will look something like this:

```
const YourContext = React.createContext();

<YourContext.Provider value={{isLoading, setIsLoading}}>
  // body
</YourContext.Provider>
```

and in the child components you can use the useContext hook.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useContext(YourContext)
setState('something')
```

Comment: But if i have multiple containers in the page that need a Loading the Loading will be applied to both of them? or if i wrap them with the Context separately the loading will be handled separately

Comment: The setState will trigger rerender in every place where the state value is used. But you have to wrap all components that will use the state. Otherwise, you will have a different value in each context.

Comment: Well technically that's what i want let's say have 2 containers sx and dx and i want to have the Loader appear at different times

Comment: So, I see 3 solutions:
1. Directly passing props with setState to the children components.
2. Create 2 contexts with a separate state.
3. Maybe the Suspense component will solve your problem: https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html#suspense

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]**

You could use render props (https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

And pass the setIsLoading function down to render function.

**[ORIGINAL]**

You can pass the setIsLoading as a prop to the child component if using context feels like an overkill.